# How to stop consuming message from kafka and stop calling REST API call of another service in case of failure

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, distributed-system

I have service A(developed in springboot) which is consuming the payloads from different kafka topics, processing it and sending to service called B using REST API. lets say due to some reason if service B goes down then how to manage this failure situation, because service A is keep listening to messages and keep calling the API of service B to send the messages. I need some mechanis to recover from this situation. Below are some ways which I thought of implementing but I am not sure whether it is reliable or not.

1. if we have any mechanism to stop consuming messages from kafka, then I can implement the same using circuit breaker pattern. (But in this case how to recover the payload which is already consumed ? and if I store it in memory cache then on restart of service A or some failure there is chances of loosing it)
2. Consume and Store the messages in the in-memory cache and on startup of service A, send all those sequentially, but here the challenge is since it's in-memory cache, there is chances of loosing it, and another challenge is of managing the sequence in memory while storing.

PS: I can't use any external storage here.

Comment: Are you performing any business logic after consuming the message in Service A and calling Service B?

Comment: Yes @SushilBehera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> service A is keep listening to messages and keep calling the API of service B to send the messages

It doesn't need to. You could retry the REST call a few times, then you would stop polling and close/pause the consumer. You also would not lose those messages until either that topic passes the retention window, and you do not commit any failed offsets.

Then you need some way to monitor when service B starts back up. One option could be Spring Actuator custom health-checking where it could frequently check remote HTTP server endpoints for connectivity. When healthy, you can unpause / recreate the consumer thread.

Spring-Kafka allows you to programmatically control the Listener with an `KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry`

Comment: when you say do not commit any failed offset, does it mean we are consuming it in transaction loop ?

Comment: Transactions are different. I mean not to call `commit` related methods on the consumer until you get a successful response from the downstream API... You should also set `enable.auto.commit=false`

Answer (score 0):

You could use another kafka topic between services A and B (assuming you can change service B to consume messages from new kafka topic).

A common approach is to have kafka error topic (also called dead letter topic) - service A can publish processed messages there if service B is unavailable. But for that you'll need a retry mechanism, that would send messages to service B from that dead letter topic.

You can also consume messages with service A and do not commit (shift consumer offset) until that message is successfully sent to the service B.

Regarding using local storage: if it's in memory, that it will be fast but fault-intolerant. If use disk storage - then it will be much slower than kafka because of I/O operations.

Comment: appreciate your answer, but I have a force restriction on using any external storage like messaging queue.